# How can I retrieve a collection of records whose last record of an association meets a criteria?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have built the query for the join but I don't know how to build the part that checks for only the last record of the association.

```
Job.where('balance != 0').joins(:ledgers).to_sql
```

`=> "SELECT \"jobs\".* FROM \"jobs\" INNER JOIN \"ledger_entries\" ON \"ledger_entries\".\"job_id\" = \"jobs\".\"id\" AND \"ledger_entries\".\"type\" IN ('LedgerEntry::JobAccount') WHERE \"jobs\".\"deleted_at\" IS NULL AND (balance != 0)"`

Pseudo-coding the rest:

`Job.where('balance != 0').joins(:ledgers).where_last_ledger_balance_equals_0`

Comment: Reverse order (id desc) and limit (1) is perchance applicable?

Comment: Nope sorry. I need to pass the condition( where the last ledger balance equals 0). I think I found the solution by other means though. Thanks.